# Flutter doctor failed with error on verbose for fresh install on Mac

Tags: flutter

Trying to setup flutter on my machine, in our org we use our own pub repository. I downloaded flutter sdk

Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 41456452f2 (5 days ago) • 2024-01-25 10:06:23 -0800
Engine • revision f40e976bed
Tools • Dart 3.2.6 • DevTools 2.28.5

flutter doctor -v

````
#1      _DefaultPub._runWithStdioInherited
(package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:447:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _DefaultPub.get (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:323:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PubDependencies.update
(package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_cache.dart:126:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Cache.updateAll (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:715:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1629:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1367:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:348:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:294:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>```

When I do flutter doctor no response
````